# after effects import output and render settings by command line

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I want to use aerender in docker to render multiple videos.
I was able to install after effects and it works so far.
But unfortunately I have a problem: I want to use a custom render- and output module template.
Normally, with gui I would just import it, but I don't know if there is a command for command line to import it, so I tried an alternative:

I copied these settings:

- Adobe After Effects 15.1 Prefs-indep-output.txt
- Adobe After Effects 15.1 Prefs-indep-render.txt

from my normal computer (from path .../AppData/Adobe/After Effects/15.1) to the config folder on the docker image

But whenever I try to run aerender, I get the following error:

> aerender version 15.1.1x12 After Effects warning: Invalid menu operation.
>   After Effects can't continue: unexpected failure during
>   application startup

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: did you solve this?